# Android - Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, android, spring, sqlite, objectbox

I would like to build an Android app. I am new to Android development, but I work with Spring Boot, so I tought it would be faster for me to write the backend with the latter and use it as a dependency for the mobile front-end. But I don't know if this architecture is possible or is it even a good pratice.

My doubts are, which database to use in alternative to sqlite? I know it's not mapped out of the box by Spring Data JPA.

Just in case the choice of using Spring Data happens to be totally unpraticable and unconvenient, which alternatives can I follow other than ObjectBox?

Keep in mind I have all the data in a postgresql db, and I use liquibase for the migration

thanks

Answer (score 1):

spring Boot and android development are two separate thanks, android development is different from normal java development.
Android development has used java concepts but has its own things such as recycler view, layouts, etc kindly learn from youtube.

Firebase is the best database for android but it is paid.

Answer (score 0):

Even though both Android and Spring Boot are written using Java, they are totally different frameworks. What you can do is to write your backend using Spring Boot and connect it to your database with ORM frameworks like JPA or Hibernate. Then, you can configure your Android app in such a way that whenever
it needs to insert or fetch data from database, it can send a request to your Spring Boot backend. Your backend will do the required fetching and insertion and send back the object to your app. Then, you can display that object in your Android app.

As for an ORM for your app, you can use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) library.